# Gmail: write add-on to send PDF of the whole thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets, gmail-addons

I am trying to switch an office from Outlook to Gmail. One of the features they are missing is the ability to drag an email conversation and send it as an attachment.

They way Outlook does, is by using their proprietary EML format. When an  Outlook client receives an EML file, they can reply directly to recipient within the EML file. It's kind of messy, but it works.

The alternative I am proposing is a Gmail script that will:

- download a thread as a PDF
- attach that thread as a PDF
- Create a new message with that PDF attached

I am looking at the [Gmail AppScript documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) and am wondering if this is possible.

It doesn't have to be PDF... but it does need to be a self-contained file with the FULL email history attached, the way it comes up in the print dialogue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the HTML body of the email, convert to PDF and save in Drive.

```
function saveEmail(Id) {
   var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
   var html = message.getBody();
   var tmpFile = DriveApp.createFile("temp.html", html, "text/html");
   DriveApp.createFile(tmpFile.getAs("application/pdf").setName("test.pdf"));
   tmpFile.setTrashed(true);
}
```

If this helps, I wrote a little [Google Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19117-save-gmail-as-pdf) to save any email message in Gmail as a PDF in Google Drive.

Comment: I need it for a whole *thread*, rather than a single email. Is that possible?